# What is the meaning of "in-pace"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "in-pace"? Here is a sample:

> And once I was caught I would have been thrown into the in–pace of some convent, to die there between two doors, withdrawn from the world.

Comment: What work is this from? I suspect it is a misprint.

Comment: Latin _in pace_, probably.

Comment: This appears to be from an English translation of the Portuguese movie "A Woman's Revenge" ?

Comment: **pace**: From Latin - ablative of pax = peace. **Pronunciation:**Brit. /ˈpeɪsi/, /ˈpɑːtʃeɪ/, /ˈpɑːkeɪ/U.S. /ˈpɑˌtʃeɪ/, /ˈpeɪˌsi/ **Also preposition** *With due deference to (a named person or authority); despite.Used chiefly as a courteous or ironic apology for a difference of opinion about to be expressed.* 1955   Times 7 July 9/6   Nor, pace Mr. Smith, was I for one moment defending immorality in the journalist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"In pace" is Latin for 'in peace', and is part of a common inscription on tombs (*requiescat in pace*, rest in peace). The origin, not given,  appears to be the English subtitles of a movie,  *A Vingança de Uma Mulher* (2012, Rita Azevedo Gomes) - as you may gather, Portuguese.  Based on a short story from Jules Amedée Barbey d’Aurevilly’s 1874 anthology *“Les Diaboliques”* (1874, "six tales of female temptresses, or she-devils, in which horror and the wild Normandy countryside combine to send a shiver down the spine of the reader"). The expression refers to the practice of immurement, walling-up, or lifelong solitary confinement, sometimes given to sinful nuns. The tradition seems to have been that of complete, utter isolation from other human beings, except that food was provided. The 'peace' of this must have resembled that of the grave. It died out in the 13th century.

> In the case of Jeanne, widow of B. de la Tour, a nun of Lespenasse, in
> 1246, who had committed acts of both Catharan and Waldensian heresy,
> and had prevaricated in her confession, the sentence was confinement
> in a separate cell in her own convent, where no one was to enter or
> see her, her food being pushed in through an opening left for the
> purpose—in fact, the living tomb known as the "in pace." ...
>
> "The cruelty of the monastic system of imprisonment known as in pace, or vade in pacem   was such that those subjected to it speedily died in all the agonies of despair."

[Immurement (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immurement)

Comment: I have no doubt you are correct, but I wish the OP had more detail...+1

Comment: @Cascabel - well, yes. The OP could have Googled all that. I wouldn't mind seeing the film, it sounds right up my street. My wife loves that kind of thing. I think that the character in the film did more than prevaricate in her confession.

Comment: Then she is an "unreliable narrator"...

Comment: "_Les Diaboliques_ consists of six tales of female temptresses, or she-devils, in which horror and the wild Normandy countryside combine to send a shiver down the spine of the reader."

Comment: Sounds like a good read...

Comment: So, can I say "dungeon" instead of "in-pace"?

Comment: By the way, how I can reach to Michael Harvey directly? I really need someone who knows English very well or a native English. Don't worry, I will not ask so much question. How can I send a private mesage to someone? I'm new on this site, and I don't know how to use it.  @Michael Harvey

Comment: Personal messages are not possible here.